# What is Python's equivalent of "perl -V"

Tags: python, perl, configuration, version, system

The output produced by running `perl -V` is packed with useful information (see example below).  Is there anything like it for Python?

---

Example output:

```
% perl -V
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 10 subversion 1) configuration:

  Platform:
    osname=linux, osvers=2.6.32-5-amd64, archname=x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
    uname='linux brahms 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 smp tue jun 14 09:42:28 utc 2011 x86_64 gnulinux '
    config_args='-Dusethreads -Duselargefiles -Dccflags=-DDEBIAN -Dcccdlflags=-fPIC -Darchname=x86_64-linux-gnu -Dprefix=/usr -Dprivlib=/usr/share/perl/5.10 -Darchlib=/usr/lib/perl/5.10 -Dvendorprefix=/usr -Dvendorlib=/usr/share/perl5 -Dvendorarch=/usr/lib/perl5 -Dsiteprefix=/usr/local -Dsitelib=/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1 -Dsitearch=/usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 -Dman1dir=/usr/share/man/man1 -Dman3dir=/usr/share/man/man3 -Dsiteman1dir=/usr/local/man/man1 -Dsiteman3dir=/usr/local/man/man3 -Dman1ext=1 -Dman3ext=3perl -Dpager=/usr/bin/sensible-pager -Uafs -Ud_csh -Ud_ualarm -Uusesfio -Uusenm -DDEBUGGING=-g -Doptimize=-O2 -Duseshrplib -Dlibperl=libperl.so.5.10.1 -Dd_dosuid -des'
    hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=define
    useithreads=define, usemultiplicity=define
    useperlio=define, d_sfio=undef, uselargefiles=define, usesocks=undef
    use64bitint=define, use64bitall=define, uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
    cc='cc', ccflags ='-D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBIAN -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64',
    optimize='-O2 -g',
    cppflags='-D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBIAN -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include'
    ccversion='', gccversion='4.4.5', gccosandvers=''
    intsize=4, longsize=8, ptrsize=8, doublesize=8, byteorder=12345678
    d_longlong=define, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=16
    ivtype='long', ivsize=8, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='off_t', lseeksize=8
    alignbytes=8, prototype=define
  Linker and Libraries:
    ld='cc', ldflags =' -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib'
    libpth=/usr/local/lib /lib /usr/lib /lib64 /usr/lib64
    libs=-lgdbm -lgdbm_compat -ldb -ldl -lm -lpthread -lc -lcrypt
    perllibs=-ldl -lm -lpthread -lc -lcrypt
    libc=/lib/libc-2.11.2.so, so=so, useshrplib=true, libperl=libperl.so.5.10.1
    gnulibc_version='2.11.2'
  Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs, dlext=so, d_dlsymun=undef, ccdlflags='-Wl,-E'
    cccdlflags='-fPIC', lddlflags='-shared -O2 -g -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector'


Characteristics of this binary (from libperl): 
  Compile-time options: MULTIPLICITY PERL_DONT_CREATE_GVSV
                        PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT PERL_MALLOC_WRAP USE_64_BIT_ALL
                        USE_64_BIT_INT USE_ITHREADS USE_LARGE_FILES
                        USE_PERLIO USE_REENTRANT_API
  Locally applied patches:
    DEBPKG:debian/arm_thread_stress_timeout - http://bugs.debian.org/501970 Raise the timeout of ext/threads/shared/t/stress.t to accommodate slower build hosts
    DEBPKG:debian/cpan_config_path - Set location of CPAN::Config to /etc/perl as /usr may not be writable.

    <snip-- iow patches galore --you get the picture>

    DEBPKG:fixes/safe-reval-rdo-cve-2010-1447 - [PATCH] Wrap by default coderefs returned by rdo and reval
    DEBPKG:patchlevel - http://bugs.debian.org/567489 List packaged patches for 5.10.1-17squeeze2 in patchlevel.h
  Built under linux
  Compiled at Jun 30 2011 22:28:00
  @INC:
    /etc/perl
    /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1
    /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1
    /usr/lib/perl5
    /usr/share/perl5
    /usr/lib/perl/5.10
    /usr/share/perl/5.10
    /usr/local/lib/site_perl
    /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.0
    /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.0
    .
```

Not to be confused with the much less informative `perl -v`:

```
% perl -v
This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
(with 53 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2009, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
python -c 'import sysconfig, pprint; pprint.pprint(sysconfig.get_config_vars())'
```

Comment: Haha, totally owned my answer.

Comment: As an aside, perl also has a module interface to the `perl -V` data: the [Config module](http://perldoc.perl.org/Config.html).

Answer (score 0):

Although this is incredibly hackish, impractical, and not as detailed as `perl -V`, this is a one-liner that can get decent information about the environment.

```
python -c "import platform as p;exec('for x in vars(p):\n try:\n  print ({x:vars(p)[x]()})\n except:\n  pass')"
```

Since this is not your typical easy-to-remember command, you could save this line to Python's `Lib` directory as `sys_info.py` and then you could just run:

```
python -m sys_info
```